# Get HDD Serial Number in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Why GetHDD Result **"_____WD-WX4645DRTEE"** , Add 5 Space .  Where is the code problem?

I added _____ instead of 5 Space.

```
Function GetHDD() As String
    Dim Wmi As Object, Disks As Object, Disk As Object
    Set Wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel" & "=impersonate}!root\cimv2")
    Set Disks = Wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
    For Each Disk In Disks
    If Len(Disk.SerialNumber) > Len(GetSerialNumber) Then GetSerialNumber = Disk.SerialNumber
    Next
    Set Disk = Nothing
    Set Disks = Nothing
    Set Wmi = Nothing
GetHDD = GetSerialNumber
Debug.Print GetHDD
End Function
```

Comment: Its not your code, its what was returned by WMI after it interrogated the driver, these things can be flaky, just trim it.